# PKCS7 padding in io.Reader wrapped BlockMode?

Tags: go, encryption

I find the `cipher.StreamReader` really neat, and have tried to implement the same for CBC (only decryption is required):

```
type BlockReader struct {
    M cipher.BlockMode
    R io.Reader
}

func (r *BlockReader) Read(buf []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = r.R.Read(buf)
    r.M.CryptBlocks(buf[:n], buf[:n])
    return
}

func Decrypter(r io.Reader, key, iv []byte) (*BlockReader, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Decrypter: %v", err)
    }
    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    return &BlockReader{M: mode, R: r}, nil
}
```

I do understand that block cipher mode is fundamentally different from CTR, but the above code actually seems to work. I don't know if it's just a coincidence, but every `r.R.Read(buf)` is always a multiple of the block size.

My main problem is to handle AES PKCS7 padding. I need a way to tell when the last read is done, so I can remove the padding. However, when `n, err := r.R.Read(buf)` is `io.EOF` the data has already been read so it's too late to remove the padding.

What can I do?

Comment: This is dangerous. If the padding turns out to be invalid it means the message has been tampered with (assuming correct key material, obviously). You should not expose any plaintext of such messages, but by providing a reader you encourage callers to consume it before it has been at least trivially verified. Yes, CBC is unauthenticated to begin with, but that doesn't mean the padding validation is worthless. If memory serves, this was part of the problem of the [EFAIL vulnerability](https://efail.de/).

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap `R` into bufio.NewReader(). Then do `Peek` in `Read()` method. If `Peek` returns `io.EOF` then remove PKCS7.

```
func (r *BlockReader) Read(buf []byte) (n int, err error) {
        n, err = r.R.Read(buf)
        r.M.CryptBlocks(buf[:n], buf[:n])
        if _, err2 := r.Peek(16/*block size*/); err2 == io.EOF {
                removePadding()
        }
        return
}

func Decrypter(r io.Reader, key, iv []byte) (*BlockReader, error) {
        ...
        return &BlockReader{M: mode, R: bufio.NewReader(r)}, nil
}
```